# filtering files in container rackspace cdn

Tags: php, api, openstack, rackspace-cloud

I am trying to write a backup script for cloudfiles (using Rackspace) , which will only copy the files that are modified since the last backup time.

Is there a way to query for a list files that are modified since a specific time ? (Using PHP )

Note: using [php-opencloud](https://github.com/rackspace/php-opencloud) library.

Comment: How many files are we talking about in the backup? Several large files or a significant number of smaller files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, I haven't found a way to query/filter based on the last modified date.

What you can do is look at the metadata for each object in a container. At a low level, this requires just a HEAD operation on each object. While this probably requires you to check each object, you're only grabbing the headers and not downloading each one.

The [last modified date is in the HTTP headers](http://docs.rackspace.com/files/api/v1/cf-devguide/content/Retrieve_Object_Metadata-d1e2301.html) when making a HEAD operation on an object:

```
HEAD /<api version>/<account>/<container>/<object> HTTP/1.1
Host: storage.clouddrive.com
X-Auth-Token: eaaafd18-0fed-4b3a-81b4-663c99ec1cbb
```

No response body is returned, but the HTTP headers have juicy details:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 07 Jun 2007 20:59:39 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 12 Jun 2007 13:40:18 GMT
ETag: 8a964ee2a5e88be344f36c22562a6486
Content-Length: 512000
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
X-Object-Meta-Meat: Bacon
```

There is a method in the PHP library called `fetch` that can get [just the headers](https://github.com/rackspace/php-opencloud/blob/master/lib/OpenCloud/ObjectStore/Resource/DataObject.php#L796-L825) of the object, but it's private and I don't see it being used [anywhere](https://github.com/rackspace/php-opencloud/search?l=php&q=fetch&ref=cmdform&type=Code). This looks like the type of thing to raise an issue on GitHub or make a PR of your own for.

Right now you can get each object and pull the headers out yourself:

```
$obj = $container->DataObject();
$headers = $obj->metadataHeaders();
$headers["Last-Modified"]
```

Sorry that doesn't help completely. I pinged one of the PHP devs directly and hopefully we'll find another option if this doesn't work out.

Comment: Kyle is right in that I don't see a filtering method. Iterating through the objects returned from container's ObjectList() method will let you check the value of last_modified. I just uploaded a file and this was my value: 2013-09-10T22:14:43.840350

Answer (score 0):

Try using [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) and [filemtime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php).

Example:

```
$lastBackupTime = 1234567890; //You'll have to figure out how to store and retrieve this
$modified = array();

// Change the input of glob() to use the directory and file extension you're looking for
foreach (glob('/some/directory/*.txt') as $file) {
    if (filemtime($file) > $lastBackupTime) {
        $modified[] = $file;
    }
}

foreach ($modified as $file) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: I suppose this code block checking a directory inside a web server. I am trying to take back up from CDN